# Measure percentage of method execution when using CodeDOM

Tags: c#, testing, codedom

I am using CodeDOM in order to execute the method (written by the user). I compile source code into a binary assembly and then execute the method with the appropriate parameters. It works fine, however I would like to measure how big part of this method was executed/get number of lines that have been executed during test run to be able to calculate percentage of coverage.
Do you know some nuget, external tool that would help me to achive that?
Thank you!

Comment: There are many tools out there.  Check out https://dzone.com/articles/a-guide-to-code-coverage-tools-for-c.  Visual Studio itself has many tools.

Comment: The thing is that I do not want to write tests, I want to check code coverage only for single method that is being executed- simply check which lines of code were excuted and which not. I need a tool that will track execution of my method (through CodeDOM as it is generated class with function from user-written code).

Comment: I know that this can be done with VS debug but I don't know of any tools that can do it at runtime.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your use case is your input is a given source code for a single method (not a whole class), your program compiles it and then executes it in a test. After the test, you want to know how much of the method was covered. The code coverage tools I've seen are all designed for reporting coverage in an IDE-type of environment, not under program control. But since you have the source code, would a low-tech solution like making a method  `I_was_here(int line)` to save the data and inserting a call to it before each line of the user's method before compiling be acceptable?

Comment: One correction: 
"your program compiles it and then executes it in a test" - no, it is happening during runtime. My program executes some part of code compiled by CodeDom on demand. 
 
"would a low-tech solution like making a method I_was_here(int line) to save the data and inserting a call to it before each line of the user's method before compiling be acceptable" - sadly it is not acceptable. I cannot modify code of script that is going to be compiled, I have access to script, and genereted by CodeDom .pdb and .dll files.